# Web Service in Java - Advanced Features - weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic

As an IT student, I have to develop a web service using Java. I have some experience in web service with .Net but not in Java, and I don't figure out how to carry out what I want and need.

So what I need : I need to develop a web service in java and a client in .Net (for windows 8 tablet). I already have a basic web service and the two applications communicate perfectly, but now I have to add some features. 
In .Net using WCF, I created a alike web service with all the features I need. Unfortunately, I can't reproduces them in Java...
Indeed, I need to send toast notification to the client (event-like behavior). I saw that weblogic (oracle's product) provided some callback annotations. It seems to be what I need but I can't figure out how to use weblogic ( I add OEPE to eclipse, but It doesn't seem to be very useful. The same for the oracle's tutorial). 
I would like to add a reference of a kind of "weblogic.jar" and use the different annotations, but it definitely doesn't work like that.

So, may you explain how to use weblogic or simply develop a full duplex web service in java (like with CallbackContract in .Net WCF) ?

Then, Does it exist a simple way to create a data contract in java like in .Net?

My questions are maybe a little bit stupid, but I didn't find useful tutorial or documentation to answer them...

Thanks

Comment: This question is pretty broad but it is possible to call Weblogic from .NET. If it were just JMS messages you could use the .dll file provided with Weblogic like what is done here: https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/jms_with_net_weblogic_server_1 If you want to make webservice type calls, you might want to look into a bridge like this one: http://www.jnbridge.com/WebLogic10ExampleInstructions.pdf

Comment: I know the question is pretty broad.Your link is very interesting, I like the idea  of a the bridge between weblogic and .Net.However it's not what I mean. I only use the .Net as a reference because it's the only things I know (for web services).I was just asking how add some features like callback method and data contract to a java WS. I mean, it's very useful to return complex type (and not only primitive type) via a web service, and to "notify" the client via a callback method (instead of 2 web service in both side).In other words:how to develop the features of a .Net web Service in Java?

Comment: Ah I understand. I don't know much about the .NET side but I am absolutely sure you can do whatever you need in Java/Weblogic. Unfortunately there are many bad questions and bad answers when searching for help. This is a solid starting place for callbacks (even though it's old): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/callback-clients-097535.html Slightly newer docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/callback.html

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this links. They seem very helpful to understand how callback works in Java/weblogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses a library called JAX-WS for working with WS. I would recommend downloading either NetBeans (free) or JDeveloper (free for developement, but as you said you are a student so it should not be a problem). Actually JDeveloper would probably be better for working with WebLogic. Some people like to use wsimport tool that comes with JAX-WS but I rather work with the built-in wizards.

For creating [WS in JDeveloper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_52/jdtut_11r2_52_1.html).

Once you have the WS implemented you can then generate a deployment descriptor for a [war](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e16272/deploy_java_ee_app.htm#ADFJE446) file and [deploy](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/tech/ias/portal/files/RG/OBE/deployToAppServer/lesson_Deployment.htm) (link might be bit old, but the idea is the same) it straight onto WebLogic Server.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look.